# How complicated is the theory of $2$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computational-complexity

Motivated by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757967/are-there-any-sets-of-axioms-that-have-an-efficient-algorithm-for-all-provable-s), I'd like to ask:

> What is the complexity of the first-order theory of the two-element pure set $\bf 2$?

(Note that the answer will be the same if we replace ${\bf 2}$ by any finite pure set with more than one element.)

The argument of my answer to the linked question shows that both $\mathsf{SAT}$ reduces to the $\Sigma_1$ fragment of this problem: there is an efficient way to transform a propositional sentence $\varphi$ into a first-order sentence $\hat{\varphi}$ such that ${\bf 2}\models\hat{\varphi}$ iff $\varphi$ is satisfiable. Dually of course this means that $\mathsf{coSAT}$ reduces to the $\Pi_1$ fragment.

Considering the behavior of adding quantifiers, a natural guess at an answer is that it should be exactly the union of the levels in the polynomial hierarchy, but I don't immediately see the details.

Comment: Well. $1$ is the loneliest number that you'll ever do. $2$ can be as bad as one, it's the loneliest number since the number $1$.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: Contrast this with $0,$ which by virtue of belonging to every other number, is the most social of all numbers.

Comment: @Dave: That's something you're going to have to take with Harry Nilsson...

Comment: "Note that the answer will be the same if we replace 2 by any finite pure set with more than one element."  The set {1, 3}, where '1' and '3' are natural numbers has the same complexity as {15.1, e} where '15.1' and 'e' are real numbers?  I find that suspicious.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The *identities* of the particular elements of a structure don't matter, and in this case the structure on our set consists of just equality (that's what "pure set" means in model theory). And in this question they **really** don't matter, since we're ultimately forgetting the structure and just looking at the theory - the set of sentences true in the structure. Digging into the particular details of what the elements "actually are" isn't something the structure can do.

Comment: So, you can't evaluate a statement like "all elements of the 3 in {1, 3} are in 1?"  Or "There exists an element of the 3 in {1, 3} which belongs to 1"?  Or "There exists an element belonging to the 3 of {1, 3} which is also in the e in {15.1, e}?"?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Not within the structure itself - those questions have to be asked/answered outside the structure, from the perspective of the set-theoretic universe. And you *know* that they have to be, since they're not isomorphism-invariant. You should look up the definition of the satisfaction relation in the context of first-order logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that Quantified Boolean Formulas is PSPACE-complete and can be reduced to the pure first-order theory of $2$, it's PSPACE-hard. On the other hand, it's also clearly in PSPACE (since the obvious recursive algorithm is polynomial in space usage). So it's PSPACE-complete.

Comment: I didn't know about QBF, thanks for bringing it to my attention!