# Complexity of the pure theory of equality

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, computational-complexity

The first-order pure theory of equality (Monk, Mathematical Logic, 240-242) has the equality predicate as its only (relation) symbol. Furthermore, I assume the convention in logic is that any interpretation of equality over a model should be the diagonal set $\{(m,m). m \in M\}$. If I'm not mistaken the quantifier-free fragment of this theory corresponds to equality logic (Kroening, D., Strichman, O., Decision procedures: an algorithmic point of view, Chapter 3) and there it is stated that it is NP-complete.

What is it known about the complexity of non quantifier-free fragments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first-order logic with only equality as a whole, $\mathsf{PSPACE}$ is an easy upper bound. It turns out to be a lower bound as well, even in a very narrow special case: already the theory of a two-element pure set is $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-complete. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797767/28111).

Note that the theory of equality - that is, the set of sentences true in *all* pure sets, or equivalently the intersection of the theories of the pure sets - inherits the complexity of $Th({\bf 2})$. Specifically, for each equality-only sentence $\varphi$, consider the sentence $$\varphi':\quad[\exists x_1,x_2(x_1\not=x_2\wedge \forall y(y=x_1\vee y=x_2))]\implies\varphi.$$ This $\varphi'$ is trivially true in every pure set of size $\not=2$ and is true in ${\bf 2}$ iff ${\bf 2}\models\varphi$. So we get that $\varphi'$ is in the theory of equality iff $\varphi\in Th({\bf 2})$; since the construction of $\varphi'$ from $\varphi$ is sufficiently simple, this means that the theory of equality is at least as complicated as $Th({\bf 2})$.

Comment: I now see why it works for $Th(\langle M,= \rangle)$ where $M$ has $2$ or more distinct elements. I guess if $M$ is empty or has one element then  the complexity is polynomial. It is not clear to me that this is what Monk means by pure theory of equality, he claims the decidability goes back to Löwenheim 1915.

Comment: @Rodrigo If $M$ has exactly one element we can get rid of all quantifiers and replace all "$x=y$"-clauses with $\top$, and check whether the resulting Boolean combination of $\top$s comes out to $\top$ or $\perp$ in linear time. If $M$ has no elements, just look at "frontmost" quantifiers: $\exists$s automatically make things false and $\forall$s automatically make things true. Again, we get linear time decidability (and constant time for prenex normal form!).

Comment: As to Monk's terminology, the pure theory of equality is the set of (first-order, with equality) sentences in the empty language (equality is taken as a logical symbol in the modern presentations) which are true in all structures (= pure sets, here).

Comment: according to your comments, the theory of pure equality is then the intersection of the theories $Th(\langle M,= \rangle)$ for $|M|  < \omega$. Two of them are of complexity $P$ and the rest are $PSPACE$-complete. The intersection does not need to be any of these. I think I can prove that all formulas in the intersection must have prefix $\forall^+ \exists^*$ and some disjunction internally should be of a specific form, which makes the problem polynomial.

Comment: @Rodrigo It's not that simple. For example, for each $\varphi$ the sentence $$[\exists x_1,x_2\forall y(x_1\not=x_2\wedge (x_1=y\vee x_2=y))]\implies\varphi$$ is in the theory of pure equality iff ${\bf 2}\models\varphi$ (it's vacuously true in all models of size $\not=2$, and is true in the remaining model iff ${\bf 2}\models\varphi$), and since the theory of ${\bf 2}$ is $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-complete this means that the theory of pure equality is $\mathsf{PSPACE}$-hard.